# Hangfire DistributedLockTimeoutException while debugging a web app in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, hangfire

I am having problems debugging a ASP.NET MVP application that uses Hangfire to handle queuing. When I start debugging in Visual Studio (databases are deployed remotely on Azure), I get a bunch of DistributedLockTimeoutExceptions and RecurringJobScheduler:Debug errors. It only occurs in during the debugging. The problem does not appear when the application is deployed and running or if I start it without debugging through VS.

What happens is that the error appears and then the app retries the connections over and over again for at least an hour (usually around 2-3 hours). After the application finally loads in, the whole process repeats for each action performed.

I would really like to debug the application but with the time required it's almost impossible and it crashes frequently. The problem sort of grew. At the beginning it was only about couple of minutes to load the application and it got progressively worse (at the beginning I haven't even seen any errors, as the loading was quite acceptable).

The error occurs multiple times, but they are all basically the same. The errors that occur frequently are as follows:

```
Hangfire.Storage.DistributedLockTimeoutException: Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller' resource.
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerDistributedLock.Acquire(IDbConnection connection, String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireDistributedLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.UseConnectionDistributedLock[T](JobStorage storage, Func`2 action)
   at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
Hangfire.SqlServer.ExpirationManager:Debug: Background process 'Hangfire.SqlServer.ExpirationManager' started.
Hangfire.SqlServer.CountersAggregator:Debug: Background process 'Hangfire.SqlServer.CountersAggregator' started.
Hangfire.SqlServer.ExpirationManager:Debug: Removing outdated records from the 'AggregatedCounter' table...
Hangfire.SqlServer.CountersAggregator:Debug: Aggregating records in 'Counter' table...
Hangfire.SqlServer.ExpirationManager:Debug: Removing outdated records from the 'Hash' table...
Hangfire.Server.Worker:Debug: Background process 'Worker #ea15664b' started.
Hangfire.SqlServer.CountersAggregator:Debug: Aggregating records in 'Counter' table...
Hangfire.Server.Worker:Debug: Background process 'Worker #eb7f9473' started.
Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler:Debug: Error occurred during execution of 'DelayedJobScheduler' process. Execution will be retried (attempt #1) in 00:00:01 seconds.


Hangfire.Storage.DistributedLockTimeoutException: Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller' resource.
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerDistributedLock.Acquire(IDbConnection connection, String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireDistributedLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.UseConnectionDistributedLock[T](JobStorage storage, Func`2 action)
   at Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
Hangfire.Server.DelayedJobScheduler:Information: Error occurred during execution of 'DelayedJobScheduler' process. Execution will be retried (attempt #2) in 00:00:03 seconds.


    System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerConnection.AcquireDistributedLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.UseConnectionDistributedLock(JobStorage storage, Action`1 action)
       at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
       at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryProcess.Execute(BackgroundProcessContext context)
    Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler:Debug: Error occurred during execution of 'RecurringJobScheduler' process. Execution will be retried (attempt #1) in 00:00:01 seconds.
```

I have already tried redeploying the application and this did not help much. I have tried to look through some mentions of similar errors online, but they did not provide many insights and the solutions provided did not work out for me.I checked for lock table, but that is not included.

There is also pretty much no jobs running on HangFire, apart from 1 every 30 minutes, but it doesn't require many resources. There are little too few problems processing the jobs otherwise.

Any help would be very welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

**First** check if your query is written optimally.

Have you made the necessary **indexes**?

add `Connection Timeout=240` in **ConnectionString**.(240 second => 4 minutes)

**Sample:** `"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Hangfire;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=hang-fire;Connection Timeout=240"`

if you use **ADO.NET** for execute query, set `CommandTimeout = 30000000;` in SqlCommand.

In that case try to add `WITH(NOLOCK)` or `WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)` to your Select statement.

**sample:** `select * from person WITH(NOLOCK) where name='amin'`